# Lua - Not displaying text in Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

In this app I'm creating with Corona SDK, when you win the text "You win" sould appear, but doesn't. I could post all the code, but I don't think the rest would be hepful, so here is only the essencial:

```
_H = display.contentHeight;
_W = display.contentWidth;
mRand = math.random;
o = 0;
time_remain = 20;
time_up = false;
total_orbs = 45;
total_secs = 20;
ready = false;

local backGround = display.newImage("media/bg.png");

backGround.xScale = 2;
backGround.yScale = 2;

loseMSG = display.newText("You Lose!", _W/2, _H/2, nil, 50)
loseMSG.isVisible = false

winMSG = display.newText("You Win!", _W/2, _H/2, nil, 50)
winMSG.isVisible = false

local countdowntxt = display.newText(time_remain, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 60);
countdowntxt.xScale = .5; countdowntxt.yScale = .5;
countdowntxt:setReferencePoint(display.BottomRightReferencePoint);
countdowntxt.x = _W-20; display.y = _H-20;
countdowntxt:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)


function winLose(condition)
if (condition == "Win") then
    bgAlpha = display.newImage("media/bgAlpha.png");
    bgAlpha.xScale = 2;
    bgAlpha.yScale = 2; 
    winMSG.isVisible = true -- Here the win text should become visible, but doesn't
elseif (condition == "Fail") then
    bgAlpha = display.newImage("media/bgAlpha.png");
    bgAlpha.xScale = 2;
    bgAlpha.yScale = 2; 
    loseMSG.isVisible = true        
end
```

end

Any Ideas why?

Comment: Lua isn't an acronym, it's a name. So it's Lua, not LUA, unless you're shouting.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, trolling caps lock ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you given nil for font value?
Atleast pass the default system font

```
loseMSG = display.newText("You Lose!", _W/2, _H/2, native.systemFont, 50)
winMSG = display.newText("You Win!", _W/2, _H/2, native.systemFont, 50)
```

Comment: I tried using the native.systemFont as well, but the result was the same, so I decided you use an image. Maybe a little bit heavier, but easier to place :) Thanks for the help anyawy

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a divide and conquer approach.

Does this work?

```
winMSG = display.newText("You Win!", _W/2, _H/2, nil, 50)
winMSG.isVisible = true <-- note this is set to true
```

It does?

Does `winLose` every get called? Put a print statement in it or a break point or whatever you use on your platform to debug.

It does?

What does the variable `condition` contain? Inspect it/print it out and verify that it is indeed "Win", same case, no spaces, etc. or you can put a print statement in the appropriate branch of that function to make sure it's being hit.

Is that OK?

Does it show up if you remove the `bgAlpha` code?

So on and so forth.

---

I don't know Corona, but Googling [the docs for `newText`](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/displaynewtext#Parameters) it's possible you have the parameters wrong (you're not passing a font).

> I could post all the code

The less you post the better, because that means you've already gone through the steps shown above to try to isolate the problem. Nine times out of ten, doing that will reveal the problem all by itself.